# An efficient way to write this code snippet?

Tags: c, performance, shortcut

Ways of rewriting this code more efficiently and/or shortly to save bytes and appear less verbose?

```
if(N % 2 == 0 && (N == 6 || N == 8 || N == 10 || N == 12 || N == 14 || N== 16 || N == 18 || N == 20 ))
{
    printf("Weird\n");
}
```

Given the language is C, although doesn't matter if its java or php or any other language :-).

Comment: Why not `N%2 == 0 && N > 5 && N < 21`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that `N` has an unsigned integral type, and you are more interested minimal source code than in clarity, then you might write

```
if (((N - 6) & 14) + 6 == N) {
    printf("Weird\n");
}
```

**Explanation**:

The first operation, `N - 6`, shifts the range of the acceptable values from `6` - `20` to `0` - `14`.  The latter range can be expressed with four bits.

The second operation, `& 14`, is a bitwise *and* with bit pattern `1110`.  That will leave even numbers in the range `0` - `14` unchanged, but it will convert odd numbers to even and it will clear any higher bits.  The only values that survive unchanged are the ones derived from the original target values in the first step.

The third operation reverses the first, so that the result can be compared directly with the original number.  If the combined sequence of operations reproduces the original number, then that number is one of the ones you were looking for.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could explain the logic behind Thai for me. I see some bit wise operations, right?

Comment: @YousufEjazi007, done.

Comment: You're a god! I'm thanks bro!!!

Answer (score 10):

Why won't you just do :

```
if (N % 2 == 0 && (N >= 6 && N <= 20))
{
     /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Damn, I wasn't fast enough :o

Comment: That's nice code.  +1

Comment: This is nothing more than my comment to the OP question...

Comment: Almost the same, yes, with a pair of parenthesis :)

Answer (score 5):

Given N is unsigned integer.

```
if(N % 2 == 0 && (N-6) <= 14)
{
    printf("Weird\n");
}
```

Comment: !(N % 2) - very bad style. Mixing boolean logic with arithmetic

Comment: Yes, of course. It does hide the actual logic, but saves bytes in source code.

Comment: Efficiency isn't about saving source code. (N % 2) == 0 will yield exactly the same binary

Comment: Yes, efficienty is about performance and less resource consumption. And both variants most likely have same efficiency, since most likely will be resolved to the same assembly code. N % 2 == 0 just has more readability. Anyway, I edited it back to how it was before.